# How to implement async | await to receive distance with geoLocation package?

Tags: flutter

I am implementing a ListView that will show a Card with the distance between the user and each card location, the location of the card is obtained from Firestore. Im using the geoLocator package but i have an issue to receive the distance, i got null when i call the method and i know that i have to use async-wait in order to wait for the value of the distance but i do not  know where to implement it.

This is the class that i call to the get the distance:

```
class Distance {
  double distance;

  void getDistance(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude,
      double endLongitude) async {
    try {
      distance = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
          startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude);

    } catch (e) {
      print('SE DISPARO EL ERROR DE DISTANCE = $e');
    }
  }
```

This is the Widget that i return:

```
Widget cardList(double userLatitude, double userLongitude) {

  double result;

  // Method to get the distance
  dynamic getDistance(double cardLatitude, double cardLongitude) async {
    Distance distancia = Distance();
    await distancia.getDistance(
        userLatitude, userLongitude, cardLatitude, cardLongitude);

    result = distancia.distance;
    return result;
  }

  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _firestore.collection('salonesInfantiles').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          ),
        );
      }

      final rooms = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;

      List<SalonesFeed> listaDeSalones = [];
      // List<SalonesFeed> listaDeSalonesDistancia = [];

      for (var room in rooms) {

        final nombreSalonText = room.data['nombre'];
        final salonLatitude = room.data['latitude'];
        final salonLongitude = room.data['longitude'];


        // This is the method that i dont know how to implement the wait in order to receive the value before the ListView is showed
double distance = getDistance(salonLatitude, salonLongitude); 
        print('result 2 = $result');

        final salonCard = SalonesFeed(
          nombreSalon: nombreSalonText,
          distanciaSalon: distance,
        );
        listaDeSalones.add(salonCard);
      }

      return Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: listaDeSalones,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I got this result:

```
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'double'
```

I also try to make it Future but still have the same issue of null

```
type 'Future<double>' is not a subtype of type 'double'
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of getDistance should be Future and you should await the response

```
double distance = await getDistance(salonLatitude, salonLongitude);
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, thanks for your comments.  If i use the "await" where do i have to write the async ?

Comment: i solved it using the FutureBuilder() with this i could catch the Future<double> of the distance =D